# Extract each week from an time interval

Tags: r, each, dayofweek, lubridate

Do you guys know, how to get the first day of each week within a time interval, using package "lubridate"?

I know I can also generate using "seq.Date", but now that I have generated a time interval and would like to use it with "%within%" later, I would like to just use this interval and get the date of each week from it.

Comment: ?floor_date should do it

Comment: @Rguy, I think floor_date will get me the first week, what about every week? I need to extract first day of each single week within this time interval

Comment: Isn't the first day of each week just every Sunday (or Monday, or whatever day you decide is the first day of a week)?

Comment: @Spacedman is also correct, the only reason to use mine over his is if you want to match each date with a factor representing which week it's in. If not, just go with his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(lubridate)
dates <- seq(Sys.Date() - 100, Sys.Date(), by = "1 days")
week.ids <- floor_date(dates, "week")
```

Now `dates` will have each of the last 100 days, and `week.ids` will have the date of the most recent Sunday before each of the dates in `dates`.  Therefore, the `week.ids` vector provides the sufficient information to group the dates by week.